# Why doesn't "Compare with Unmodified" work in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Ran into this today, but I couldn't add my solution to the Visual Studio forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/17952/team-explorer-git-compare-with-unmodified-not-work.html

I was unable to compare my changes to the unmodified version via the "Compare with Unmodified" context menus or by double clicking the file in the "Changes" view.

Solution posted below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I created my branch, I named it `poc/my_branch_name`. When I went to do a `push -u origin poc/my_branch_name` (pushing to Visual Studio Team Services), it failed. I tracked that down to the fact that we already had a "POC" branch (note the case sensitivity). I changed it to `push -u origin POC/my_branch_name` and that worked fine.

I did my work and then came back later to view changes and sync commits, and Visual Studio just silently failed. I remembered the folder name, did a `git checkout POC/my_branch_name` and all of a sudden I was able to perform "Compare with Unmodified" and view pending commits.

Essentially, branch folder names in VSTS are case sensitive.

Comment: Visual Studio is case-insensitive just like Windows.  GIT is case-sensitive (perhaps case-sensible is a better description.  It's as though HEAD is different than head or MacDonald is different than Macdonald, cuz in fact they are and so should they be.

Comment: @RickO'Shea, the problem isn't case-sensitivity in GIT, the problem is that VSTS (now Azure DevOps) was interpreting part of the branch name as a folder. There was an issue because I had previously created "POC/old_branch", then created "poc/new_branch", and the latter had problems.
Also, you can be helpful without the snark.